# Boolean-valued model and ctm

Tags: logic, solution-verification, set-theory, boolean-algebra

In Bell's *Boolean-valued Models and Independence Proofs* (third edition), the author describes the "forcing over the universe" approach in the first two chapters and how to get corresponding ctms in chapter 4. However, instead of the usual definition $M[G]=\{\sigma_G:\sigma\in M^{(B)}\}$, where $B$ is a complete boolean algebra in a ctm $M$, $M^{(B)}$ is the collection of all $B$-names in $M$ and $\sigma_G$ is the evaluation of $\sigma$ w.r.t. the generic filter $G$, the author defines an equivalence relation $\sigma\sim_G\tau$ as $\big\|\sigma=\tau\big\|\in G$ and forms the quotient $M^{(B)}/G$, and then spends several pages showing that this model is well-founded. Does the usual definition $M[G]$ work here (of course it does, but I am wondering if there is a quick way to transfer previous results about $M^{(B)}$ to $M[G]$)?

I believe $M[G]$ works so I attempted to show that for any $B$-sentence $\phi$, $M[G]\models\phi\Leftrightarrow\big\|\phi\big\|\in G$ by induction on $\phi$. Here is the quantifier step (although similar thing appears in atomic case):

$M[G]\models\forall x\phi(x)\Leftrightarrow\forall\sigma\in M^{(B)}, M[G]\models\phi(\sigma)\Leftrightarrow\forall\sigma\in M^{(B)}, \big\|\phi(\sigma)\big\|\in G$,

where the second equivalence is by induction hypothesis. Now I want to conclude that $G\ni\big\|\forall x\phi(x)\big\|=\bigwedge_{\sigma\in M^{(B)}}\big\|\phi(\sigma)\big\|$. Let $U=\{\big\|\phi(\sigma)\big\|:\sigma\in M^{(B)}\}$ and $D=\{x\in B\setminus\{0\}:(\forall a\in U,x\leq a)\lor(\exists a\in U,x\leq a^*)\}$ ($a^*$ is the complement of $a$). To me it seems like $D$ is a dense set that belongs to $M$ (since $U\in M$). Then there is some $x\in G\cap D$, and because each $a$ belongs to $G$ it cannot be $x\leq a^*$, so it can only be $\forall x\in U, x\leq a$, i.e., $x\leq\bigwedge_{\sigma\in M^{(B)}}\big\|\phi(\sigma)\big\|$.

Is this argument correct? I thought it was but then I realized the same argument shows that if $D\subseteq G$ and $D\in M$ then $D$ has a (nonzero) lower bound in $G$. This seems too strong and probably wrong, plus I haven't found it in any book.

Comment: What do you mean by "the usual definition"?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mean the definition of forcing extension using evaluation of names, which is sketched in the rest of that sentence. I thought this was the common one in contrast to the definition using equivalence classes of names.

Comment: Even in the "common" definition each set has a lot of different names. It's just that with the standard interpretation we get the extensionality sort-of-built in, but with Boolean-valued models we need to take a quotient, since different names are not necessarily forced to be equal by the maximum condition.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes quotient works but what about the usual way of taking a generic filter and evaluating names? As you said it gives you extensionality (indeed well foundedness) immediately and looks cleaner, assuming the argument in my question is correct.